# How to get Mutual Friends and display results in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a lot of problems getting mutual friends between users and displaying those mutual friend's picture, userid and names in a while loop. I have tried nearly every answer on SO on mutual friends but when I mix all of the column's needed for the while loop, everything breaks down. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Friends** Table:`friend_id, friend_one, friend_two, date`

**Users** table: `uid, name_f, name_l, profile_pic`

When users add one another as friends, I record the following. Let's assume that user 1 and user 2 are now friends:

`friend_one: 1, friend_two: 2, Date`

`friend_one: 2, friend_two: 1, Date`

I would need something like the following, the sql query only return the number of mutual friends for me but doesn't help me select the user's uid, profile pics and names:

```
$friends_sql=mysql_query("SELECT b.friend_two FROM (SELECT friend_two FROM friends WHERE friend_one = $myvar1) a INNER JOIN (SELECT friend_two FROM friends WHERE friend_one = $myvar2) b ON a.friend_two = b.friend_two");
                while($friends=mysql_fetch_array($friends_sql))
                {
                something
                ?>
                <li>


 <img of user><p>name of user</p><a hre>link to user's uid</a>
</li>

                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: I would get the list of user ID's first and then looped through them

Comment: what's the output of `print_r($friends)` in the while loop?

Comment: It just sends back an array with a list of friends.

Comment: Just? that's exactly what you need! can you post the output of that array so I will be able to write for you a solution? `print_r`

Comment: Agh! On second look it's only outputting one of the mutual friend's IDs. Here's the output: "Array ( [0] => 7 [friend_two] => 7 ) mutual friends" Number 7 is the userid of a mutual friend. But when I do a mysql_num_rows, it properly spits out all of the mutual friends in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the next code works for you?

```
$friends_sql=mysql_query("SELECT b.friend_two FROM (SELECT friend_two FROM friends WHERE friend_one = $myvar1) a INNER JOIN (SELECT friend_two FROM friends WHERE friend_one = $myvar2) b ON a.friend_two = b.friend_two");
                while($friends=mysql_fetch_array($friends_sql))
                {
                     $getMutualFriendInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='{$friends['friend_two']}'");
                      $MutualFriendInfo = mysql_fetch_array($getMutualFriendInfo);
                ?>
                <li>


 <img src="<?=MutualFriendInfo['profile_pic']?>"><p><?=MutualFriendInfo['name_f'] ?> <?=MutualFriendInfo['name_l'] ?></p><a href="/user.php?uid=<?=MutualFriendInfo['uid'] ?>"></a>
</li>

                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: If I could leap through my computer, I'd give you a huge. This did it perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Ofir, just a side question. Do you know how I would go about showing a top 3 suggestions of the users one could add based on mutual friends? Basically, imagine that you are logged in and your uid is 10, on the side of the page you see a 'Suggested friends list' that displays the 3 users in the db that you share the most mutual friends with (#1 - user=>25 (share 30 mutual friends) #2 - user=>92 (share 12 mutual friends) #3 user=>4 (share 2 mutual friends). Any ideas?